# L10N - How to add translated Strings not necessarily of UI elements?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to provide the option to switch between two languages in my mobile application. I have already saved a l10n bundle file in my `src` directory where the basic UI `String` elements are translated, e.g. "cancel", "ok", etc..
I would like to also add `String` objects that are part of user feedback, `Form` titles, etc.. How do I use the "Add property" of the designer tool in this case? Should I declare and initialize all related `String` objects as static fields?

[image: "Add Property" option in Designer tool.]
[image: "Add Property" input window.]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the key strings as usual and once you install the bundle into the `UIManager` it should seamlessly apply to all elements.

You should never use statically initialized fields for this since their lifecycle isn't clear. The app loads the resource in init(Object) and until that's called the app might not be running. The resource might be inaccessible.

Comment: I am not sure I get this. When I add a property, what is expected in the input window?

Comment: I don't follow that. It's possible I didn't understand the original question. What input window?

Comment: Well, I attach a couple of screenshots in the original article to clear the miscommunication.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://www.codenameone.com/how_di_i/how-do-i-localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html
It's just the strings you have in the UI. E.g. "Form Title" is the property "Translated Form Title" will be the value for each language bundle.

Comment: I have not watched it. I will. So it picks up automatically any registered `String` object and returns the translated one when another locale is selected. Thank you.

Comment: When it comes to the blog-like knowledge base, consider revamping it somehow to make it easier navigating into subjects. The search function is not the most convenient, especially when it returns lots of results. Some kind of classification in conjunction with a tag cloud perhaps would offer a little bit better usability. I do not suggest to disable the search box though.

Comment: Shai, in case the static method of `String` class is used, `format()`, how do I handle it? I mean there are in the string placeholders, e.g. `%s`. Do I include them as part of the property?

Comment: You can include them in the String. Notice that `str.format()` isn't supported in Codename One.

Comment: Well, I refer to the static method of the `String` class, which is part of the Java SE 8. Everything works fine in the simulator.

Comment: Are you using Ant with IntelliJ? If so this will only fail when you try to send a build. I suggest migrating to Maven which performs compliance checks in the simulator too.

Comment: Wait, before migrating anything, `str.format()` is not the same as `String.format()`. Would you mind clearing this first, to make sure there is a reason to move to Maven?

Comment: Generally there's a reason to move to maven since that's the future. But you don't have to right now. If you'll send a build you'll see the same result, compilation will fail for these methods since they aren't there.Both.

Comment: Ok. I just checked the codename one javadoc and you are right. I used Java SE 8 javadoc for this one, wrongly presuming compatibility, because I thought it is a very basic functionality that would be supported. I will switch to `Stringbuilder` before attempting a build. However, this is unnecessarily complicating UX design which is a big deal.
As for Maven, we are in accordance.